# ASP.NET MVC How to debug a published folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Good day Someone.

I am new to asp.net mvc.

I created a simple web application using asp.net mvc.

The application is used to upload image from to a folder. The application works well in visual studio, but once i publish and put on iis it does not upload the image.

I am thinking if there is way to debug the published version so that i can get where the issued is ?

Kindly help on how i can debug the published version and how to solve the problem .

Below is where it is catching the error

```
 string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetLocation, file.FileName);
```

Comment: Research "remote debugging".

Answer (score 0):

I Would suggest doing the debugging for ASP.NET MVC Application to follow the below points.

Server-side - You should use do exception filter to write any issues to text files and track it

Front - End -  the developer tool in the browser level for javascript related things.

DataBase Side - You can use the SQL profiler to use catch the server-side debugging.

Answer (score 0):

add try catch block in your codes

and in the catch code log the exception error message into a file in server to see what is the exact error as following:

add this model to your solution under "Models" folder or anywhere

```
public class ExceptionLogger
    {
        private string sLogFormat;

    
        public void ErrorLog(string sErrMsg)
        {
            try
            {
                string LogDirectory = "C:\LogFiles\";
                CheckCreateLogDirectory(LogDirectory);
                LogDirectory = (LogDirectory + "Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-us")) + ".txt");
                sLogFormat = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-us")) + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-us")) + " ==> ";
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(LogDirectory, true);
                sw.WriteLine(sLogFormat + sErrMsg);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { 
            }
        }
        private bool CheckCreateLogDirectory(string LogPath)
        {
            bool loggingDirectoryExists = false;
            DirectoryInfo oDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(LogPath);
            if (oDirectoryInfo.Exists)
            {
                loggingDirectoryExists = true;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(LogPath);
                    loggingDirectoryExists = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                    // Logging failure
                }
            }
            return loggingDirectoryExists;
        }
        
    }
```

---

Then in your controller or repository where errors may happen do the following:

a- add this code in top:

```
ExceptionLogger Err = new ExceptionLogger(); 
//you need to write "using" in top to refactor the import error
// something like this: using YourProjectName.Models;
```

b- in your code blocks add try catch block

```
try{
    //your code 
}catch(Exception ex){
    Err.ErrorLog(ex.Message + " --- , ---- " + ex.InnerException);
}
```

---

another way is to add OnException event on your BaseController which will detect any error or exception, hence you can log it without try-catch blocks, do it as following:

define this in your baseController: `ExceptionLogger Err = new ExceptionLogger();` with its using then add the event:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    var isSent = false;
           
    if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || !filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (new HttpException(null, filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode() != 500)
    {
        return;
    }
            
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
    {
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = new
            {
                error = true,
                message = filterContext.Exception.Message
            }
        };
        LogError("Controller: AjaxCall" + " Action: AjaxCall" + filterContext.Exception.Message, filterContext.Exception);

    }
    else if (filterContext.Exception is HttpAntiForgeryException)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError(); //make sure you log the exception first 
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Logout", controller = "Account" }));

    }
    else
    {
        var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
                 

        if (actionName == "_Menu")
        {
            isSent = true;
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/Logout");
        }
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "~/Views/Error/Error.cshtml",
            MasterName = null,
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model),
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };
        ////Redirect or return a view, but not both.
        LogError("Controller: " + controllerName + " Action: " + actionName + filterContext.Exception.Message, filterContext.Exception);
    }

    // log the error by using your own method

    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    if (isSent == false)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
    }

    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
}


private void LogError(string message, Exception exception)
{
    Err.ErrorLog(message + " && " + exception.Message);
}
```

---

now when errors happen then you will go to c:/logfiles folder in the server and find the exact error happened